# Word break is not working after grouping with cloned objects in fabric js

Tags: fabricjs

I am adding `breakWord=true` in textbox and then if i am grouping those textboxes word break is working but if I am using cloned and then doing group with cloned objects word break is not working.

Write Something in textbox at list two lines without space and press normal group button and then clone group button. `breakWord=true` will not work for clone group.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ayan27/mGa3k/115/)

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var text1 = new fabric.Textbox('Thisisthesampletext', {
  left: 10,
  top: 20,
  width: 100,
  breakWords: true
})

var text2 = new fabric.Textbox('thisisthesampletext', {
  left: 100,
  top: 60,
  width: 100,
  breakWords: true
})


 
canvas.add(text1,text2);

fabric.Textbox.prototype._wrapLine = function(ctx, text, lineIndex) {
var lineWidth        = 0,
    lines            = [],
    line             = '',
    words            = text.split(' '),
    word             = '',
    letter           = '',     
    offset           = 0,
    infix            = ' ',
    wordWidth        = 0,
    infixWidth       = 0,
    letterWidth      = 0,
    largestWordWidth = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    word = words[i];
    wordWidth = this._measureText(ctx, word, lineIndex, offset);
    lineWidth += infixWidth;

    // Break Words if wordWidth is greater than textbox width
    if (this.breakWords && wordWidth > this.width) {
        line += infix;
        var wordLetters = word.split('');
        while (wordLetters.length) {
            letterWidth = this._getWidthOfChar(ctx, wordLetters[0], lineIndex, offset);
            if (lineWidth + letterWidth > this.width) {
                lines.push(line);
   line = '';
                lineWidth = 0;
            }
            line += wordLetters.shift();
            offset++;
            lineWidth += letterWidth;
        }
        word = '';
    } else {
        lineWidth += wordWidth;
    }

    if (lineWidth >= this.width && line !== '') {
        lines.push(line);
        line = '';
        lineWidth = wordWidth;
    }

    if (line !== '' || i === 1) {
        line += infix;
    }
    line += word;
    offset += word.length;
    infixWidth = this._measureText(ctx, infix, lineIndex, offset);
    offset++;

    // keep track of largest word
    if (wordWidth > largestWordWidth && !this.breakWords) {
        largestWordWidth = wordWidth;
    }
}

i && lines.push(line);

if (largestWordWidth > this.dynamicMinWidth) {
        this.dynamicMinWidth = largestWordWidth;
    }

    return lines;
};


canvas.on('text:changed', function(e) {
 
 text2.setText(e.target.text);
 
 }); 



function group(){
var group = new fabric.Group([text1, text2], {
   left: 100,
   top: 200,

});

 canvas.add(group);

}
 function cloneGroup(){
  var group2 = new fabric.Group([text1.clone(), text2.clone()], {
   left: 200,
   top: 300,

});
 canvas.add(group2);

 
 }
```

```css
canvas{
 border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.9/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="500" height="600"></canvas>
<button onclick="group()">Normal Group</button>
<button onclick="cloneGroup()">Clone Group</button>
```